Flutter apk white screen after release
In debug mode my app works but once the apk is built, any place where there is a call to the API(need connection) managed by the flutter_bloc and http, my widgets are no longer displayed (white screens) except AppBars. internet permission added in manifest.
And what's weird is sometimes the apk works well and other times it doesn't.
Flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.5, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19045.4170], locale fr-TG)
• Flutter version 3.19.5 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 300451adae (2 weeks ago), 2024-03-27 21:54:07 -0500
• Engine revision e76c956498
• Dart version 3.3.3
• DevTools version 2.31.1
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\look\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\look\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\look\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+0--11185874)
• All Android licenses accepted.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.26)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
• Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 version 16.11.33529.622
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+0--11185874)
[√] VS Code (version 1.88.0)
• Flutter extension version 3.86.0
[√] Connected device (4 available)
• TECNO BD2 (mobile) • 063211515C009845 • android-arm    • Android 10 (API 29)
• Windows (desktop)  • windows          • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19045.4170]
• Chrome (web)       • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 123.0.6312.106
• Edge (web)         • edge             • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 123.0.2420.81
[√] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.
• No issues found!

Can you share the manifest file and pubspec.yml file

When developing Flutter applications, it's essential to be aware of differences in handling exceptions between debug and profile/release modes.
If you're encountering gray screens in flutter's release mode, it's likely due to unhandled exceptions during widget rendering (mostly related to data handling).
So, I recommend running the app in debug mode and checking console logs and devtools. (You should see an exception that complains).

Here are some of the causes of white screen on release

It is caused by missing assets in the drawable folder
It can also be caused by wrapping widgets in a parent that has no
anchors like width and height

. For example
    Scaffold(
    body: Column(
    children: [
       GridView.count(...),
...other widgets
    ]))

In that example GridView has no anchor points since it is in Column, you can give it size by wrapping it in a SizedBox and giving it height and width

-it can also be caused by wrapping widget a wrong parent to widget like   the Expanded  is usually used wrongly by a lot of flutter
developers

For example;
Scaffold(
    body: Column(
    children: [
       Text("Demo text 1"),
       Expanded(children: Column(
      children: [
          Text("Demo text 2"),
        ])
     ]))

The expanded widget needs to have an anchor point from the direction you are expanding from in its parent, so in this case, you need to give it a parent that will have height and width to act as an anchor point

The other thing that can cause the problem is the Flexible(..)
widget which must be handled in a parent with a size
Lastly Make sure the permission you have in your debug AndroidManifest.xml file like internet permission, etc, is the
same as of the main AndroidManifest.xml file


I finally solved that. It was the use of this class that caused the problem
    class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData? _mediaQueryData;
  static double? screenWidth;
  static double? screenHeight;
  static double? defaultSize;
  static Orientation? orientation;

  //

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData!.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData!.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData!.orientation;
  }

  //
}

